# How to get the APIs present in a particular block in a CFG using Angr?

Tags: binary-analysis, malware, static-analysis, angr, program-analysis

I'm doing binary analysis based on Control Flow Graph (CFG). As I suppose to get the APIs from every block in the CFG. I'm finding it very difficult to do so using Angr as I don't have enough grip on Angr. Could someone please answer this?

If it is not possible with Angr, please suggest another alternative solution.